# Brezis' exercise 6.16: prove that $\sigma(T) \subset \{-1, 1\}$ and determine $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \neq \pm 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a real Banach space. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$, i.e., $T:E \to E$ is a bounded linear operator. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. Let $\rho(T)$ be the [resolvent set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1345626/368425) of $T$. Let $\sigma(T)$ be the spectrum of $T$, i.e., $\sigma(T) := \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
>
> 1. Assume that $T^2 = I$. Prove that $\sigma(T) \subset \{-1, 1\}$ and determine $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \neq \pm 1$.
> 2. More generally, assume that there is an integer $n\ge 2$ such that $T^n=I$. Prove that $\sigma(T) \subset \{\pm 1\}$ and determine $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \neq \pm 1$.
> 3. Assume that there is an integer $n\ge 2$ such that $T^n=0$. Prove that $\sigma(T) = \{0\}$ and determine $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \neq 0$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt (2). Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

Let $\lambda \neq \pm 1$.

1.

We have
$$
(T-\lambda I)(T+\lambda I) = (T+\lambda I)(T-\lambda I) =T^2-\lambda ^2 I = (1-\lambda^2) I. \tag{1}
$$

It follows from $(1-\lambda^2) I$ being bijective [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238116/368425) both $(T-\lambda I)$ and $(T+\lambda I)$ are bijective. Hence $(T-\lambda I)$ is bijective and thus $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. So $\sigma(T) \subset \{-1, 1\}$.

It follows from (1) that
$$
(1-\lambda^2) (T-\lambda I)^{-1} (T+\lambda I)^{-1} = I.
$$

On the other hand,
$$
(T+\lambda I) (T+\lambda I)^{-1} = I.
$$

Hence
$$
(1-\lambda^2) (T-\lambda I)^{-1} = T+\lambda I,
$$
and thus
$$
(T-\lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{T+\lambda I}{1-\lambda^2}.
$$

2.

Consider the polynomial $p(t) := t^n-\lambda^n$ for $t \in \mathbb R$. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117674/368425)
$$
p(t)= (t-\lambda) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} t^k \lambda^{n-k-1}.
$$

We have $p(T)$ is bijective because
$$
p(T) = T^n-(\lambda I)^n = (1-\lambda^n) I \tag{1}.
$$

On the other hand, we [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724178/is-it-true-that-qt-circ-rt-rt-circ-qt-for-all-q-r-in-mathbb-rx)
$$
 (T-\lambda I) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1} \overset{(2)}{=}  p(T) \overset{(3)}{=} \left ( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1} \right ) (T-\lambda I) \tag{4}
$$

It follows from (2) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238116/368425) $(T-\lambda I)$ is surjective and $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1}$ is injective. It follows from (3) [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2238116/368425) $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1}$ is surjective and $(T-\lambda I)$ is injective. Then both $(T-\lambda I)$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1}$ are bijective. In particular, $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. Then $\sigma(T) \subset \{\pm 1\}$.

It follows from (2) that
$$
 (T-\lambda I) \frac{1}{1-\lambda^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1} = I.
$$

Then
$$
 (T-\lambda I)^{-1} = \frac{1}{1-\lambda^n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T^k \lambda^{n-k-1}.
$$

3.

This is the same as the previous question with $p(T) = -\lambda^n I$.